# Question about a Question's Answer

Tags: discussion

So if I find a question from several years ago that obviously doesn't have any current activity how can I ask a question about an answer given to that question? I know that if I open a new question and reference that question it will get downvoted and most likely closed. If I comment on the old question will it be seen by the people who answered the question or not?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you would ask?  If you are just asking how does this work I can see you getting a negative response.  If you ask a detailed question on what parts of the answer you don't understand and why then that should be okay.

Comment: yea.. basically the question was reguarding an android application and the OP had 2 activities with one main activity, but I have 3 activities and was just wondering if how to apply it to my app vs. their app... but my main point in this question is should I start a new question referencing that question or should I comment on the old question?

Comment: wait... you have a solution to get 2 activities and you need a third one? Unless I'm REALLY out of whack with android (to be fair I don't really do mobile dev), you should be able to adapt the answer of 2 to 3... Anyway if you have a precise case, link the question? People will be able to give you more detailed information ^^

Comment: @thatdude1087 you should really edit that kind of information into your actual question.

Comment: I would say unless you try to adapt it and fail and show what you tried and what your problem is it would just get marked as a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I ask a question about an answer given to that question? ....If I comment on the old question will it be seen by the people who answered the question or not?

Comment on the post (once you have 50 reputation).  The owner of the post is *always* notified when someone comments on it or edits it.  You can "ping" up to one additional user in the comment string with `@username`.  Then both the post owner and the other commenter will get a notification.

> I know that if I open a new question and reference that question it will get downvoted and most likely closed

Why do you think this is the case?  Yes, poorly researched questions will be downvoted, and some may be closed as duplicates.  But if you take your time to write a good question, there is no reason why your question can't stay and even get upvotes.  If you have a specific question about the answer, and you clearly indicate the parts that you do understand and the ones you don't, that would be a decent question.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on the question you would ask and the type of answer needed to suit you.

If you are going to ask something really simple that isn't clear to you in the answer and the response would be something like "you can add this variable here" then I would start with a comment and see if you get a response.

If your question will need a more detailed answer **and it will be potentially helpful to others**, then go ahead and ask a new question and link to the older one. Just make sure to be clear *what* you don't understand about the given solution.